# calculate cosine similarity of two words in R?

Tags: r, vector, nlp, cosine-similarity

I have a text file and would like to create semantic vectors for each word in the file. I would then like to extract the cosine similarity for about 500 pairs of words. What is the best package in R for doing this?

Comment: Are you trying to create cosine similarity based on word representation (based on one hot encoding) or use Word2Vec or some other word embeddings?

Comment: Based on word representation. What are the advantages/disadvantages of using Word2Vec?

Comment: It really depends on what your task is and your data. Say if you have smaller maybe few paragraphs of data; then the matrix is sparse and could nearly be singular. Advantage of Word2Vec is using pre-learned word embeddings in n-dimensional space. Cosine similarity on Word2Vec space works miraculously in most cases.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand your problem correctly, you want the cosine similarity of two vectors of words. Let us start with the cosine similiarity of two words only:

```
library(stringdist)
d <- stringdist("ca","abc",method="cosine")
```

The result is `d= 0.1835034` as expected.

There is also a function `stringdistmatrix()` contained in that package which calculates the distance between all pairs of strings:

```
> d <- stringdistmatrix(c('foo','bar','boo','baz'))
> d
  1 2 3
2 3    
3 1 2  
4 3 1 2
```

For your purpose, you can simply use something like this

```
stringdist(c("ca","abc"),c("aa","abc"),method="cosine")
```

The result are the measure for the distances between `ca` and `aa` on the one hand and `abc` compared with `abc` on the other hand:

```
0.2928932 0.0000000
```

**Disclaimer:** The library [stringdist](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/stringdist/) is brand new (June 2019), but seems to work nicely. I am not associated with the authors of the library.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `lsa` library. `cosine` function of the library gives a matrix of cosine similarity. It takes a matrix as input.

Comment: error while inserting **strings** into the `cosine()` function. It requires _numeric/complex matrix/vector arguments_ as an input.

Comment: For a full working example, see e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34045738